# Unity - Reduce iOS AppStore release size

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Hi i am building an iOS game using Unity2018.1.5 but for some reason my game size is way too big after publishing to the AppStore , i tried building it for Android and got 34Mb but when building for iOS i get 193Mb on the AppStore. I reduced the max size of my sprite to 512 because my game is just in 2D and pixel format. I looked everywhere and tried to reduce everything but the size is always large on the iOS. I found that some people disable the bitcode so i did that, and it did reduce the size to 60mb but i don't know if this is a good approach or not because i don't even know what bitcode does. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem once for a project, and it has been the same since then, bitcode is used for debugging if I recall correctly, you can bypass it tho as you already know.

What we discovered the first time we had the issue is that the installing and download sizes are different, and iOS shows the user the install size, so the app is not downloading the 60Mb, but something around 34 Mb but keeping on phone 60 Mb for it.

Try to confirm this by downloading it with a phone with mobile data on and let the phone measure it.

I hope that this helps or that I am not telling nonsense.

Comment: yes i did confirm this when the size was 193Mb, it didn't download 193Mb but more like 80Mb . But when the user sees 193Mb they won't download it that's why i think i'll just disable the bitcode and hope it doesn't mess up something.

Comment: We do the same, just disable bitcode and hope it does not surpass 100 Mb U.U

Answer (score 0):

When you are just building for test, disable Bitcode. It won't create any problem. But When you'll upload the final version for app approval, then enable Bitcode. Bitcode is used by apple reviewer team for additional debugging.

When your game will be approved and uploaded in the app store, it will show the size without Bitcode. I hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i did that and it still show the size with the Bitcode on the AppStore :(

Comment: Have you already uploaded the game? If not, I think in your developer account it shows the install size of the game. Try seeing the universal game size with other apple devices.

Comment: Yes I already uploaded it, in universal for download size it's 80mb and install size is 240mb and this is what it shows on the AppStore (240mb)

Comment: Same thing, did you find a solution?